# Got wrong data by ImageReader when reading from a video?

Tags: android, video

I am writing an app to grab every frame from a video,so that I can do some cv processing.
According to Android `s API doc`s  description,I should set Mediaplayer`s surface as ImageReader.getSurface(). so that I can get every video frame on the callback OnImageAvailableListener .And it really work on some device and some video.
However ,on my Nexus5(API24-25).I got almost green pixel when ImageAvailable.
I have checked the byte[] in image`s Yuv planes,and i discover that the bytes I read from video must some thing wrong!Most of the bytes are Y = 0,UV = 0,which leed to a strange imager full of green pixel.
I have make sure the Video is YUV420sp.Could anyone help me?Or recommend another way for me to grab frame ?(I have try javacv but the grabber is too slow)

Answer (score 1):

I fix my question!!
when useing Image ,we should use getCropRect to get the valid area of the Image.
forexample ,i get image.width==1088 when I decode a 1920*1080 frame,I should use image.getCropImage() to get the right size of the image which will be 1920,1080

Comment: just wondering, what video format did you use here? and what did you set your ImageReader format to?

Comment: @hiro can you please share a solution ?